# Reading only numbers in CSV file C#

Tags: c#, csv

I have a CSV file with values:

```
,Vb(M),Ke23(M^-1),
AAA,3.91E-06,2.21E+06
BBB,6.65E-03,3.50E+03
CCC,0.213,1503.759398
DDD,1.37E+00,0.00E+00
```

I want to read the file and store only the number values in the CSV file.

I would like to do this by manipulating the code that is featured here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/415732/Reading-and-Writing-CSV-Files-in-Csharp

Or is there an easier way to just read and store the numbers?

Comment: When you say "just store number values" can you explain what you mean. Perhaps include another block of what you would like the CSV to look like instad? (wrap the text in `<pre></pre>` like I did so it looks nice after you paste it.)

Comment: i have variables i declared that I would like them equal to:

so AAA.Vb = 3.91E-6 
and AAA.Ke23 = 2.21E6 and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer i was able to get from @evanmcdonnal's answer:

```
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"F:\BP1.csv");
        List<double> numbers = new List<double>();
        double buffer = 0;

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            string[] tokens = line.Split(',');

            foreach (string s in tokens)
            {
                if (double.TryParse(s, out buffer))
                    numbers.Add(buffer);
            }
        }

        foreach (double d in numbers)
            Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());
        reader.Close();
```

output: 
3.91E-06
2210000
0.00665
3500
0.213
1503.759
1.37
0

Gives what i was looking for.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

It's fairly simple, just loop over the lines of the file splitting on commas, then loop over the tokens using `TryParse` something like this should work;

```
List<double> numbers = new List<double>();
double buffer = 0;
while (string line = reader.ReadLine() != null)
{
      string[] tokens = line.Split(',');
      foreach (string s in tokens)
      {
          if (double.TryParse(s, out buffer))
              numbers.Add(buffer);
      }
}

// to print the values with iteration
foreach (double d in numbers)
     Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());

// to print with LINQ
numbers.Select(x => Console.WriteLine(x.ToString()));
```

Disclaimer: I wrote the code in browser so it hasn't been compiled or tested. Some minor adjustments might be necessary but that's pretty much the simplest way to do it.

Comment: His numbers aren't integers.

Comment: code doesnt work for me.  I want to assign each value to a specific variable.  So AAA.Vb = 3.91E-6 and AAA.Ke23 = 2.21E6 and so on

Comment: @BBH1023 Then instead of getting each number on a list, parse them into some other structure.

Comment: @BBH1023 each number is in it's own variable, each of those are in a list. How else would you expect to do it? I'll add a snippet to operate on the values but it sounds like you need read up on arrays and Lists since what you're suggesting in that comment is completely unreasonable and would never be used in real code.

Comment: when i write Console.WriteLine(numbers.Count) after your code it's giving me 0.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @BBH1023: it sounds like none of the numbers parsed as a double correctly therefore nothing was added to the list.  The .TryParse function returns a bool to let the caller know if the parse was successful.

Comment: galford's analysis is likely correct. The real question is why `TryParse` is failing. It sounds like you may have to use this version of the method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx although the msdn docs show examples of the default using scientific notation (though it's a little different than yours).

Comment: I dont understand why TryParse is failing.  even if I substitute a .csv file containing the line 1,2 it still fails and returns false.

Comment: @BBH1023 well that certainly shouldn't happen. Set a break point at the top of the loop and confirm that the contents of the `line` and then the contents of `s` are what you'd expect them to be. I would expect the file isn't be read as you expect it to be because if `tokens = { 1, 2 }` it will succeed.

Answer (score 1):

A LINQ solution:

```
var numbers = File.ReadLines("file.txt")
    .SelectMany(line => line.Split(','))
    .Select(token =>
    {
        double value;
        return double.TryParse(token, out value) ? (double?)value : null;
    })
    .Where(value => value != null)
    .Select(value => value.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) for parsing CSV files. It can easily give you strongly typed access to your file so you can easily pick out the number values as simple properties.

Here is a quick example of parsing your data with Filehelpers, to get the second column.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(MyRecord));
        MyRecord[] myRecords = engine.ReadFile("data.csv") as MyRecord[];
        var numbers = myRecords.Select(x => x.ColumnB);
        foreach (var number in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    [DelimitedRecord(",")] 
    public class MyRecord
    {
        public string ColumnA;

        [FieldConverter(typeof(ScientificNotationConverter))] 
        public double ColumnB;

        [FieldConverter(typeof(ScientificNotationConverter))] 
        public double ColumnC;
    }

    public class ScientificNotationConverter : ConverterBase
    {
        public override object StringToField(string @from)
        {
            return Double.Parse(@from, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've used FileHelpers and I do like it.  Another nice Csv reader is http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader. It's may not be quite as robust as FileHelpers but it is pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could try something like this.

**note: this assumes a perfectly formed CSV file such as you provided.  you need to include error checking otherwise it is sure to fail at some point**

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("MyCsvFile");
Dictionary<string, double> parsedCsv = new Dictionary<string,double>();

// Read the first line
string col1 = "", col2 = "";
if(lines.Length > 0)
{
    string[] tokens = lines.Split(',');
    col1 = tokens[1];
    col2 = tokens[2];
}

for(int i = 1; i < lines.length; i++)
{
    string[] tokens = lines.Split(',');
    string varName1 = tokens[0] + "." + col1;
    string varName2 = tokens[0] + "." + col2;
    double value = double.Parse(tokens[1]);
    parsedCsv.Add(varName1, value);
    value = double.Parse(tokens[2]);
    parsedCsv.Add(varname2, value);
}
```

Now you can access a value form the dictionary like so.

```
double AAA1 = parsedCsv["AAA.Vb(M)"];
double AAA2 = parsed Csv["AAA.Ke23(M^-1)"]
```

and so on.

Keep in mind I have NO error checking.  I'm only showing a way to associate the parsed in values with some variable association at runtime via a Dictionary<>.  I didn't include how to use the linked CsvReader library.  If you have questions specifically about how to use it I would ask another question.

Comment: for the     string[] tokens = lines.Split(','); line dont you need to specify the element of the array?  code is giving me an error here and also it's throwing an exception for double AAA1 = parsedCsv["AAA.Vb(M)"]; asking for a key

Comment: the line string[] tokens = lines.Split(','); will take the line and split it into an array of strings.  so for example val1,val2,val3 would be split into an array of 3 string {"val1", "val2","val3"}.

Comment: was the exception "The given key was not found in the dictionary"?  That would mean the value didn't parse correctly.  However, I would have expected there to be an issue @ double.Parse(tokens[1]) as that will throw an exception if the value cannot be parsed.